# Math.Round() not actually rounding my doubles

Tags: c#, ieee-754

I'm trying to return a `double` that is rounded to two decimal places. I've stepped through and verified that, along every step of the way, all of my values are `doubles`. Here's my method:

```
public double FindAzimuthAtPointK(LwdData pointKData, SurveyData stationOne, SurveyData stationTwo)
{
    var deltaDepth = stationTwo.MeasuredDepth - stationOne.MeasuredDepth;

    var valueG = FindValueG(pointKData, stationOne, stationTwo);
    var valueH = FindValueH(pointKData, stationOne, stationTwo);
    var valueY = FindValueY(stationOne, stationTwo);

    var sinStationOneInclination = Math.Sin(RadianToDegreeConversion * stationOne.Inclination);
    var sinStationTwoInclination = Math.Sin(RadianToDegreeConversion * stationTwo.Inclination);

    var sinStationOneInclinationSquared = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(RadianToDegreeConversion * stationOne.Inclination), 2);
    var sinStationTwoInclinationSquared = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(RadianToDegreeConversion * stationTwo.Inclination), 2);

    var partOneBottom = ((180 * deltaDepth) * Math.Tan(RadianToDegreeConversion * (valueG*valueY) / 2)) / (Math.PI * valueY);

    var partOneTotal = Math.Pow((valueH / partOneBottom), 2);

    var partTwo = sinStationOneInclinationSquared * sinStationTwoInclinationSquared;

    var topTotal = RadianToDegreeConversion * (partOneTotal - partTwo);

    var bottom = 2 * sinStationOneInclination * sinStationTwoInclination;

    var acosValue = Math.Acos(topTotal / bottom);

    var azimuthAtPointK = stationOne.Azimuth + acosValue;

    return Math.Round(azimuthAtPointK, 2);
}
```

Here's the actual math equation(and subequations), hand written by the client:
[image]
[image]

Now, what's actually happening here is that the return value is `315.57999999999998`, when it should be `315.58`. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Try using the `decimal` type rather than `double`. It might be an issue with precision which double is lacking in.

Comment: Actually it is 'Must' and 'Is' rather than 'Try' and 'Might' :-)    Double is not so much about 'double precision' it is about double the range that is covered with _some_ accuracy. And as they are binary only powers of 2 are represented __accurately__

Comment: The likely problem is that the number you don't like is as close to 315.58 as can be represented with a double. This just comes with the territory when using floating point numbers.

Comment: What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (From 1991)

Answer (score 5):

It's all about the precision of doubles and the numbers they can accurately represent. Use a decimal if you need absolute accuracy or round your result at the end for display purposes.

To answer your question about rounding at the end, it may be that your result of 315.58 can not be accurately displayed as a double to 2DP.

Comment: *...or round your result at the end* as in when displaying the value, presumably.

Comment: Which is what I'm doing. I'm not rounding it until it's the final result which will displayed.

Comment: Also bare in mind that the algorithm is based upon the "Bankers" approach, so what you think maybe rounding up instead rounds down.In Visual Basic (both currently and pre-.NET) conversions from floating-point numbers to integers uses bankers rounding (round-to-even). This makes sense given VB’s usage in finance/line of business applications to avoid the bias that accumulates with the other rounding methods. When you write, in Visual Basic CInt(1.0) the compiler emits a call to Math.Round(1.0) and then converts the result of that call to an Int32.